# Поиск номера строки в коде

Tags: c

Есть ли способ на Си отследить номер строк. То есть например вот наш код :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func1(int a){
 char z;
}
int func2(int a){
 int x, y, z;
 float x;
 func1(x);
}
int main( ){
 int a, var1;
 func1(a);
 func2(var1);
}
```

Нам нужно примерно так:

```
Input function: main
Result:
11: int main( ){
Input function:
func1
Result:
3: int func1(int a){
9: func1(x);
13: func1(a);
```

Есть ли какой нибудь способ так сделать на чистом Си?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь сделать стектрейс ручками? или просто ищите `__LINE__` ?

Comment: Ручками, возможно ли это?

Comment: Если аккуратно логировать все входы и выходы, то вполне возможно. Только непонятна решаемая задача. Может Вам лучше изучить отладчик, дампы?

Comment: По заданию не сказано как реализовать данную задачу. Если слишком муторно реализовать руками, то возможно, что можно и с помощью __LINE__. Но как он работает в Си на примере, который я показал?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте такой вариант. Я сделал специальный макрос `IN`, который нужно вставлять там, где нужно залогировать номер строки имя функции. В студии следует использовать `__FUNCTION__`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define IN printf("%d:%s\n", __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

int func1(int a){
 IN
 char z;
}
int func2(int a){
 IN
 int x, y, z;
 //float x;
 func1(x);
}
int main( ){
 IN
 int a, var1;
 func1(a);
 func2(var1);
}
```

Comment: А не подскажите, что означает __PRETTY_FUNCTION__?

Comment: это такой макрос, вместо которого препроцессор подставляет имя текущей функции. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html